# How can I have a shadow around undecorated jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dropshadow

I have an undecorated JFrame

[image: here]

and I dont like the fact that it doesnt have a drop-shadow like a decorated jframe. I want to put a dropshadow on it.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the Border of the JFrame. The Border is different for the platform that you are using.
Read up on [How to user borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

You might be able to use an existing Border or if you wn the full effect of the shadow you will likely need to implement your own custom Border. Does a JInternalFrame have a Border like that? If so then maybe you can use:

```
Border border = UIManagerDefaults.getBorder("InternalFrame.border");
```

[Original answer, comment #4](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/49740-undecorated-jframe-background-shadow.html)

Comment: Thank you, but my frame already has a border, so replacing my current border isn't an option.

Comment: Put all your frame contents inside a `JPanel`, add this `JPanel` containing all the components to the `JFrame`. Set the border of the `JPanel` to the border your frame currently has, then set the `JFrame`'s border to the shadowed border. This should allow you to have two borders.